# Redis expiration, memory leak by specification?

Tags: memory-leaks, redis, ttl

[Redis](http://www.redis.io/) provides us with the `EXPIRE` and `TTL` functions. According to the [documentation](http://www.redis.io/commands/ttl), the `TTL` command can be used to distinguish between a non-existent and an expired key:

```
> SET foo 3
OK
> GET foo
"3"
> EXPIRE foo 5
(integer) 1
> TTL foo
(integer) 3
> TTL foo
(integer) 2
> TTL foo
(integer) 1
> TTL foo
(integer) 0
> TTL foo
(integer) -2
```

According to the [EXPIRE specification](http://www.redis.io/commands/expire#how-redis-expires-keys), expired objects are actually removed from the store either when they are accessed, or through a periodic random selection of expired keys:

> Specifically this is what Redis does 10 times per second:
>
> Test 20 random keys from the set of keys with an associated expire.
>
> Delete all the keys found expired.
>
> If more than 25 keys were expired, start again from step 1.

But what about the `-2` (or the information which allows to generate it in place of the `-1`)? Is it kept forever or is there a garbage collection policy?

Also notice how if we set and delete a new value for the same key, the `-2` will survive:

```
> SET foo 3
OK
> ttl foo
(integer) -1
> del foo
(integer) 1
> ttl foo
(integer) -2
```

So, for instance, let's say we have a scripts which keeps setting keys with incremental names and makes them expire after 1 second. After an arbitrarly long time, are we going to exhaust the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the page on [Redis as a Least-Recently-Used Cache](http://redis.io/topics/lru-cache) -- you can tell Redis to not exceed a set amount of memory, and select one of several key expiration and purging policies.

A subtle issue is that not all data types in Redis play nice with this, but sets with ttl set should work.  There is also support for enough logging for you to keep track of what happens why and how as you tune this.

Answer (score 4):

> But what about the -2 (or the information which allows to generate it in place of the -1)? Is it kept forever or is there a garbage collection policy?

`-2` indicates that the key's not in the database, e.g.:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> flushall
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> ttl somekey
(integer) -2
```

Comment: Yes. This is the point. The question was about how we get rid of the `-2`, because if we cumulate `-2` for infinite keys we are going to exhaust our memory. Very slowly, of course.

Comment: No additional memory is needed for that - it is the equivalent of EXISTS for that matter.

Comment: Well, we already have an answer but... How can it not need additional memory? There must be a data structure somewhere which recalls which keys were associated to a timer, otherwise how could the system remember where to put the `-2`? Implementation-wise, in redis, I expect some dictionary-like strucutre to exist somewhere, and the expired key is using a slot of it.

Comment: -2 means that the key doesn't exist - it was either expired or never created in the first place (see the example in my answer).

Comment: Knew it will happen if I insisted ;) Go out and do since real damage now!